# Custom Gradle Task having Kotlin Delegate

Tags: kotlin, gradle, delegation

Gradle tasks using Kotlin are implemented as either `abstract class ...` or `interface ...`.
In either case it is not clear how to use delegation.
The following works correctly but requires delegation to be performed manually (i.e. it does not use Kotlin delegation).

```kotlin
@CacheableTask
abstract class FooTask : DefaultTask(), CopySourceSpec {

    @get:InputFiles
    @get:Optional
    @get:SkipWhenEmpty
    @get:IgnoreEmptyDirectories
    @get:PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
    abstract val sourceFiles: ConfigurableFileCollection

    @TaskAction
    fun canonize() {
        val sourceFileTree = sourceFiles.asFileTree
        // do something with the sourceFileTree
    }
    
    override fun from(vararg sourcePaths: Any?): ProtobufHeaderTask {
        this.sourceFiles.from(sourcePaths)
        return this
    }
    override fun from(sourcePath: Any, closure: Closure<*>): ProtobufHeaderTask {
        this.sourceFiles.from(sourcePath, closure)
        return this
    }
    override fun from(sourcePath: Any, configureAction: Action<in CopySpec>): ProtobufHeaderTask {
        this.sourceFiles.from(sourcePath, configureAction)
        return this
    }
}
```

It seems like this could be done more simply using Kotlin delegation.

```kotlin
@CacheableTask
abstract class FooTask : DefaultTask(), ConfigurableFileCollection by sourceFiles {

    @get:InputFiles
    @get:Optional
    @get:SkipWhenEmpty
    @get:IgnoreEmptyDirectories
    @get:PathSensitive(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)
    abstract val sourceFiles: ConfigurableFileCollection

    @TaskAction
    fun canonize() {
        val sourceFileTree = sourceFiles.asFileTree
        // do something with the sourceFileTree
    }
}
```

This latter case produces an error that `sourceFiles` is not defined.
Is it possible to use Kotlin delegation in this way?

Comment: I can't answer the Kotlin specific question. Are you not able to extend `org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy` instead? There is little to no reason to implement a lot of Gradle interfaces because Gradle does that automatically for many of its types or provides default implementations such as the aforementioned `Copy` task type.

Comment: Yes I am aware that extending Copy (actually AbstractCopyTask) can be done to achieve similar results. What I want to know is whether Kotlin class level delegation can be used when developing a custom task.